# Why my simple angular example can not work on fiddle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cdn, jsfiddle

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input ng-model="msg" />
<p my-dctv >
    {{msg | myUpperFilter }}
</p>
```

```
// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller`enter code here`
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "hello world";
});

// add a filter
myApp.filter("myUpperFilter", function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.toUpperCase();
    }
});

// add a directive
myApp.directive("myDctv", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
            element.css("background", "yellow");
        });            
        element.bind("mouseleave", function() {
            element.css("background", "none");
        });            
    }
});
```

Error Message:     No module: myApp

Here's my fiddle work block
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/TabrisK/r4sqLkgo/#&togetherjs=Aq6TooFwad)

I just copy from
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/JKBbV/)

And External Resources has also copied.

Comment: Where is the fiddle ?

Comment: Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dn6dzv0b/

Comment: Your code is fine. problem is in including js file in fiddle. try in codepen or plunker

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya absolutely correct

Comment: I have already solved the problem.Where the right-top corner have a button,We have to set LOAD TYPE as No wrap-in< body >.

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything perfectly, except including the `angularjs` file. Although, you have added it as an external file, but it is advisable to include from the list available in the *jsFiddle* itself.

In the *javascript* section, on the right top, there is an icon of *Settings*, on click of it, it opens up a popup, which asks for some stuffs.

Select the following in it -:

1. LANGUAGE > Javascript
2. FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS > AngularJS 1.2.1 (or any other version)
3. LOAD TYPE > No wrap - in head
4. FRAMEWORK SCRIPT ATTRIBUTE > (do not change)

By this you would be able to see your code running in *jsFiddle*.

For your reference I have forked out your code into a new one.

Refer [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/6wnyb5ep/) for the same.